# when ios application in the inactive state how many secs to takes to go to the background state

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am developing android and ios mobile application using Nativescript angular. I am used progress bar in ios application. I want to know when ios app in the inactive state how many secs to takes to go to the background state.

Comment: As soon your app is paused, if you are running a background task it will be triggered immediately. If you are running a service, you can not predict when exactly it will be triggered, it depends on the system and what type of background mode you choose.

Comment: I am using a timer in the foreground. If the application is idle in 30mins, the app will be entered in the background?

Comment: On IOS, Your code will stop executing, all network calls will be paused, even the timer as soon app is pushed to background. App may go into background if user receives a phone call / pressing home button etc., You must probably store the timestamp on pause event and compare it on resume event to calculate the total idle time (app in background).